# Debug Prime Program

Tags: c++, primes

I'm working on this program that determines if a number is prime.  I don't get any errors when compiling, but the output is not right.  Can anyone tell me what is wrong (and how to fix it?)?

```
#define PROMPT "Please enter a whole number: "
#define NOT_PRIME "The number is not a prime number! "
#define PRIME "The number is a prime number "
#define DONE 0
#define FIRST_FACTOR 3

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main(){
   int i;
   char number;

   cout << PROMPT;
   cin >> number;

 for (i=FIRST_FACTOR; i<=number; i++){
        prime = true;
        for (int n=2; n<=i-1; n++){
           if (i%n == 0){
              prime = false;
           }
        }
        if(prime){
           cout << number <<  PRIME << endl;
        }
        else{
           cout << number <<  NOT_PRIME << endl;
        }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm doens't make sense.  What's the outer loop for?  Shouldn't you be checking `number % n`?

Comment: number should be an `int` not a `char`.

Comment: You should prefer `const std::string`, `const int` etc. instead of `#define`

Answer (score 3):

The biggest issue is that your program always prints `number` when it should be printing `i`.

```
    if(prime){
       cout << i <<  PRIME << endl;
    }
    else{
       cout << i <<  NOT_PRIME << endl;
    }
```

Another issue is that you declared `number` as `char` rather than `int`.

Other than that, your program is working ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/6yp2Ot)), but sub-optimal.

To make it optimal, consider these changes (in the order of increasing challenge):

- Don't test even numbers for being prime: at the end of the loop print another message saying that `i+1` is not prime, and increment `i` by two.
- Stop when you reach square root of the candidate: in other words, instead of `n<=i-1` in the `for` loop write `n*n <= i`
- Store a list of the primes that you found so far; rather than testing all possible factors from `2` to `sqrt(i)`, test only the primes that you have already found.
- Consider switching to [a more advanced algorithm for finding primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: I think the program is supposed to check if `number` is prime, so the output makes sense in that context.  The outer loop on `i` seems weird and wrong to me though.

Comment: @CarlNorum It looks like the program is expected to go through numbers from 3 to `number`, inclusive, and print which ones are primes and which ones are not.

Comment: Yes, that's what the algorithm looks like it's doing, but that doesn't match with the prompts and the OP's first description: "... this program that determines if a number is prime."

Answer (score 1):

Your issues are:

- number should be an int or unsigned int.
- The second for loop makes no sense.
- Your control flow is to complex, make it simpler.

Here is what I think a solution should look like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Please enter a whole number: " << std::endl;
    unsigned int number;
    std::cin >> number;

    for (unsigned int i = 2; i * i < number; i++) {
        if(number%i == 0) {
            std::cout << "The number is not a prime number! " << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }

    }

    std::cout << "The number is a prime number " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're looping twice in your code you can change it to something like

```
if (number % 2 == 0) prime = false;

for (i = 3; i <= sqrt(number) && prime; i+=2)
    if (number % i == 0) prime = false;
```

Realize that a number's highest divisor (that can divide it evenly) is equal to it's square root so you don't need to check more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your supposed to loop twice in order to continue asking for new entries until they enter 0.

```
#define PROMPT "Please enter a whole number: "
#define NOT_PRIME " is not a prime number! "
#define PRIME " is a prime number "

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main(){

   int number;
   bool prime;

   while (true)
   {
      prime = false;

      cout << PROMPT;
      cin >> number;

      if (number == 0) break;

      int MaxPossibleFactor = (int)(sqrt(number) + 1);

      if ((number % 2) == 0)
      {
         prime = true;
      }
      else
      {
         for (int i=3; i<=MaxPossibleFactor; i += 2)
         {
            if ((number % i) == 0)
            {
               prime = true;
               break;
            }
         }
      }

      if (prime)
      {
         cout << number << PRIME << endl;
      }
      else
      {
         cout << number << NOT_PRIME << endl;
      }
   }


   return 0;
}
```